# Display of ggplot crashes R

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I am trying to create a plot with `ggplot()` from the `ggplot2`-package, but R crashes as soon as I execute my code, like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=year, y=value, fill=variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.85)
```

This occurs in multiple versions of RStudio and in RGUI, too (in contrast to the problems described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/1ZmaTiwca9o)). It happens with any call to `ggplot`, even when a dataframe instead of data.table is used as input.

When I save the plot in a separate object it does not crash immediately. However, as soon as I try to print the plot, everything crashes as well.

```
test_plot <- ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=year, y=value, fill=variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.85)
print(test_plot)
```

I can produce plots outside of the `ggplot2`-package just fine.

I have seen reports of `ggplot2` causing crashes, but these were two years ago and were deemed an RStudio bug, which does not seem to be the case here.

Has anyone seen this behaviour and, more importantly, how can I solve it?

## Edit:

This also happens when I don't print the plot, but try to save it with `ggsave()`:

```
ggsave("test.png", test_plot, device = "png")
```

---

## Data and session info

```
dt <- structure(list(year = c("2014", "2015", "2016", "2014", "2015", 
        "2016"), variable = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"), value = c(82.1, 
        47.8, 60.8, 706.6, 580.2, 128.4)), .Names = c("year", "variable", 
        "value"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
        -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x102009f78>)

sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1       data.table_1.10.4-3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.3-2 scales_0.5.0     compiler_3.4.3   lazyeval_0.2.1   plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.4.3      pillar_1.2.1     gtable_0.2.0    
[9] tibble_1.4.2     yaml_2.1.18      Rcpp_0.12.15     grid_3.4.3       rlang_0.2.0      munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. `ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=year, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.85)` works fine for me. Note that you're missing a closing bracket in the `ggplot(...)` command. It's also missing in the `ggplot(...)` command in `test_plot`.

Comment: Have you tried to install the development version of ggplot2? `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`

Comment: Added the missing bracket, thanks. I have just tried your suggestion, @MarcoSandri but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often, issues like these can be resolved by ensuring `ggplot2`, and any of the R packages that it depends on, are up-to-date. You can try something like the following:

```
deps <- tools::package_dependencies("ggplot2", recursive = TRUE)$ggplot2
for (dep in deps) {
  try(install.packages(dep))
}
```

This might end up re-installing some packages you might already have installed, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: I was a bit hesitant about the answer, because I just freshly installed everything two days ago, but it finally works! Thank you very much. The code "as is" didn't work smoothly, though. I removed the base packages from `deps` (via `sessionInfo()$basePkgs`) and now I have my plots!

Comment: Awesome! One of the frustrating things is that occasionally order of installation can matter (e.g. if you installed pkg A that depends on pkg B, but pkg B was too old at time of installation) so you might've run into an issue of that form.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue with ggplot2 crashing in R 4.1.0 as well.